# How to pass php array of objects into google's geo chart data to generate chart?

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have got php array here like below

```
[0:{Count: 4, name: "Melaka", region: "HQ"}
1:{Count: 2, name: "WP-Kuala Lumpur", region: "HQ"}]
```

i want to generate google geo chart by passing above data to google visualization geo js library.

someone could help on this. Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful to see the code that creates the array, and any attempt at drawing the chart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to fetch the data and parse it to JSON. Create an array  in javascript, iterate the json data and assign the values to the array. Then pass the array data to the data attribute of the chart.